# How do I use PowerShell to replace text in files using a template file and the filename in place of placeholder text

Tags: powershell, replace, foreach

I have a template file: Agriculture.txt, which includes the word "Agriculture" in several places.

I have about 30 files in a folder, including Agriculture.txt, each with no text except for the Agriculture file.

I want to replace the text in each file with the content of the Agriculture file, and replace the word "Agriculture" in each file with the name of the file (minus the .txt extension.)

I tried using these powershell commands:

```
$Content = Get-Content C:\Temp\Technologies\Agriculture.txt

$FileList = Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\Technologies\ | select FullName

$FileList | ForEach-Object { ($Content).replace("Agriculture",$_) | Set-Content $_.FullName }
```

I get an error message:

> Cannot find an overload for "replace" and the argument count: "2". At
> line:1 char:30
> ... ch-Object { ($Content).replace("Agriculture",$*) | Set-Content $*.Ful ...
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Can someone help me fix my Powershell commands?

Thanks!

New commands:

```
$Content = Get-Content -Raw C:\AMD\Temp\Technologies\Agriculture.txt

$FileList = Get-ChildItem C:\AMD\Temp\Technologies\

$FileList | ForEach-Object { ($Content).replace("Agriculture",$_.BaseName) | Set-Content $_.FullName }
```

Is that right?
*EDIT* Those last commands worked. Thank you, Santiago!

Comment: remove `| select FullName` then do `$Content.Replace("Agriculture", $_.BaseName)` and lastly, `Get-Content` should use `-Raw`

Comment: Does that mean my 3 commands would look like this?

$Content = Get-Content -Raw C:\AMD\Temp\Technologies\Agriculture.txt

$FileList = Get-ChildItem C:\AMD\Temp\Technologies\

$FileList | ForEach-Object { ($Content).replace("Agriculture",$_.BaseName) | Set-Content $_.FullName }

Comment: Seems like that should do the trick.

Comment: @TBowman, please consider sharing the working solution in the form of an _answer_, to benefit future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New commands:

```
$Content = Get-Content -Raw C:\AMD\Temp\Technologies\Agriculture.txt

$FileList = Get-ChildItem C:\AMD\Temp\Technologies\

$FileList | ForEach-Object { ($Content).replace("Agriculture",$_.BaseName) | Set-Content $_.FullName }
```

Answer courtesy Santiago!